# I am looking for QTP containing inputbox kind of method in java

Tags: java, qtp

I am new to the java,I have experience in QTP. In the QTP we have inputbox built-in function. so at runtime while developing program we can give input value using inputbox function. So, I am looking for similar method in the java.Can you please help me any built in method is available in the java?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What tool are you talking about in Java? Is it selenium?            QTP is a automation tool so you can fairly compare with tools in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Java scanner class here as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int a;
      float b;
      String s;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      s = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered string "+s);

      System.out.println("Enter an integer");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered integer "+a);

      System.out.println("Enter a float");
      b = in.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("You entered float "+b);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JOptionPane class in java for generate InputBox like QTP. You can also generate the MessageBox like QTP and print the message.

**For InputBox and store the value in String format:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String First=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Message or Number");
        String Second=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Message or Number","Input Value",JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
        }
```

**For MessageBox and print the message:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Welcome to My Message.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to My Message.","Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: **See this link for more:** ** [Automation Hub Point]** (http://swatantrapage.blogspot.in)

Comment: [**I am looking for QTP containing inputbox kind of method in java**] (http://swatantrapage.blogspot.in/2015/06/i-am-looking-for-qtp-containing.html)